# How to update maven dependency in jhipster web application

Tags: spring, maven, jhipster, spring-social-facebook, jhipster-registry

I am using JHipster for my web application development.
I am using JHipster facebook login feature.
Now I have updated my JHipster version to 4.0.7
so my facebook login is not working.Previous  version of"spring-social-facebook.version" is 2.0.3.RELEASE 
After googling for solution I have changed it to

`<spring-social-facebook.version>3.0.0.M1</spring-social-facebook.version>`

But when I am executing my application by **gradlew** command . it's not downloading the new version files. Please help me out.Am I missing something. or there another way to update the maven dependencies

My _pom.xml file is as follows

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-social-facebook</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0.M1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: did you run ./mvnw command?

Comment: no its a gradle project . i used to run gradlew command

Answer (score 0):

Just feeling confused by your question mixing gradlew, maven and _pom.xml which is a template for JHipster to generate your project's pom.xml if using maven.

If you use gradlew, the deps versions are in gradle.properties file.

Comment: its a gradle project. but it has maven wrapper also

Comment: Then you did something custom as JHipster does not allow you to create such a hybrid build and I can't help you. Anyway you have to choose one tool, what's the point of keeping both?

Comment: its a gradle project. but it has maven wrapper also.
This _pom.xml file is present inside node_modules. Below is the path
C:\SATYAJIT\ABC\le3\node_modules\generator-jhipster\generators\server\templates\_pom.xml

Comment: _pom.xml in node_modules is a template used by generator-jhipster when generating your project, don't touch it. Anyway, if it's a gradle project, you should clean it up and delete maven wrapper and edit gradle.propertied as I said.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the spring milestones repository

```
<spring-social-facebook.version>3.0.0.M3</spring-social-facebook.version>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-social-facebook</artifactId>
    <version>${spring-social-facebook.version}</version>
</dependency>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>Central</id>
        <url>http://central.maven.org.maven2</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>String milestones</id>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```